# Get ordered group last item

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a list of items related to users.

Each item have a date.
I want to get the last item (by date) of every user

For example if data is:

```
Id1, User1, 1.1.16 
Id2, User2, 2.1.16 
Id1, User1, 4.1.16 
Id4, User2, 3.1.16 
Id3, User1, 2.1.16 
Id4, User2, 5.1.16
```

It should return the last item (by date) of each of the users:

```
Id1 User1 4.1.16
Id4 User2 5.1.16
```

My query is:

```
from sf in db.Items
where ...
group i by i.UserId into g
select g.OrderByDescending(s => s.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

For some reason it always gets the first item of the user.
When i print all the groups and their items it looks OK and the
first item is the last in the each group but the query doesn't return it.

I tried to change to `g.OrderBy`..didn't help
also tried to add `g.ToList()`...
How can I get the latest item of every user ?

It does work if im changing the query to 
...
group i by i.UserId into g 
select g.OrderByDescending(s => s.StartDate)

and than when i loop on groups i take first item 
foreach (var g in Query)
 
{
 var last = g.First();

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
var result = from sf in db.Items
             where ...
             group i by i.UserId into gr
             select new 
             {
                 UserId = gr.Key
                 LatestItem = gr.OrderByDescending(s => s.StartDate)
                                .FirstOrDefault()
             };
```

Having made the grouping then you project each group into an anonymous type object with two properties. The first property is the key of the group, `UserId`. While the second is the `LatestItem` for this user.

Comment: Unfortunately im getting the same reault. Its wroking only if i select the entire group and than when i loop on groups i select First.   foreach (var gr in resultQuesry)  var last = gr.First();